# Debugging MIL failure on Windbg

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

Recently started using Windbg, as I have heard it is a great tool for debugging purpose.

There is a lot of help online on how to use windbg and the different extensions available. During my learning I constantly come across the below failure on Windbg while I am running some particular workload.

Failure:
*MIL FAILURE: Unexpected HRESULT 0x8000ffff in caller: CDwmAppHost::OnUnhandledException*

I tried finding help online from Google and MSDN. Maybe, I missed out something, hence could not get any help on it.

So, please, can someone help me in

-> understanding what this error message means?

-> How do I debug it? are there any extensions or other tools available to debug it?

P.S: English is not my native language, so please apologies if there are any grammatical or speling mistakes.

Comment: Where is the message from? Is it debug output?

Comment: Yes, it is in the debug output!

Answer (score 0):

-> understanding what this error message means?

I don't think this message is something related to WINDBG. This is being spewed from the code that you are running. Basically when running under the debugger - if you code spews any debug messages that will get shown in WINDBG.

So to know more about what this error message means, search through your code for text displayed.

-> How do I debug it? are there any extensions or other tools available to debug it?

Like i said above, start with text search in your code to see where this message comes from - that would  be your starting point !

Happy Debugging :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I understand this is spewed from some code. But, No where in my code I am dealing with exceptions in my code as MIL failures.

Comment: Well in that case it is very likely that you are using some other 3rd party binaries or binaries from the OS, which is responsible for this message.
You may try the steps mentioned by Thomas below!

Answer (score 0):

The message looks like a debug message, not an exception. Debug messages can be sent by the programmer using the [OutputDebugString() method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To check if that's really the case, you can use [SysInternals DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx). If the message shows up there when not using WinDbg, then it's true.

Since the text of a debug message is specified by the programmer, the text can be more or less meaningful. It can also be a message of a library (DLL) used by the program.

If you want to see the callstack when the message is printed, you can issue the command

```
sxe out
```

WinDbg should then stop whenever debug output is written. I'm not so sure what could be interesting at that point, here are some tries:

```
k; *** Callstack
!gle; *** Get last error
g; *** Go (wait for next debug output)
```

Comment: Dear Freakoster, if this answered your question, please accept it as the solution using the checkmark on the left side of this answer, thank you.